# What is equivalent of Perl DB_FILE module in Python?

Tags: python, perl

I was asked by my supervisor to convert some Perl scripts into Python language. I'm baffled by few lines of code and I am also relatively inexperienced with Python as well. I'm an IT intern, so this was something of a challenge.

Here are the lines of code:

```
my %sybase;
my $S=  tie %sybase, "DB_File", $prismfile, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666, $DB_HASH or die "Cannot open: $!\n";
$DB_HASH->{'cachesize' } = $cache;
```

I'm not sure what is the equivalent of this statement in Python? DB_FILE is a Perl module. DB_HASH is a database type that allows arbitrary keys/values to be stored in data file, at least that's according to Perl documentation.

After that, the next lines of code also got me stumped on how to convert this to the equivalent in Python as well.

```
$scnt=0;
 while(my $row=$msth->fetchrow_arrayref()) {
     $scnt++;
     $srow++;
     #if ($scnt <= 600000) {
    $S->put(join('#',@{$row}[0..5]),join('#',@{$row}[6..19]));
    perf(500000,'sybase') ;#if $VERBOSE ;
    #   }
 }
```

I'll probably use fetchall() in Python to store the entire result dataset in it, then work through it row by row. But I'm not sure how to implement join() correctly in Python, especially since these lines use range within the row index elements -- [0..5]. Also it seems to write the output to data file (look at put()). I'm not sure what perf() does, can anyone help me out here?

I'd appreciate any kind of help here. Thank you very much.

Comment: A quick glance at the Python standard library documentation shows [`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html) and for Berkely DB (LIke `DB_File`; moved to a standalone library in Python 3) [`berkeleydb`](https://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm).